# Migrating Umbraco 7 website to 11: filter items in a node

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco8, umbraco9

I try to migrate my website from Umbraco 7 to 11

I have the following code on 7:

```
var Section_node = Umbraco.Content(1234);    

var Section_pages = @Section_node.Children.Where("Visible");
Section_pages = Section_node.DescendantsOrSelf().Where("NodeTypeAlias == @0", "blogPosts");
```

So I try to convert it to 11 (.net 7) as follow:

```
var Section_node = Umbraco.Content(1234);    

var Section_pages = Section_node.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible());
Section_pages = Section_node.DescendantsOrSelf().Where(NodeTypeAlias("@0")).And().Field("NewsPage");
```

But I'm still getting errors - any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what is the error you get?

Comment: The type arguments for method 'NPocoSqlExtensions.Where<TDto>(Sql<ISqlContext>, Expression<Func<TDto, bool>>, string?)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

Returns:

An IEnumerable<out T> that contains elements from the input sequence that satisfy the condition.

Exceptions:

  ArgumentNullException
The type arguments for method 'NPocoSqlExtensions.Where<TDto>(Sql<ISqlContext>, Expression<Func<TDto, bool>>, string?)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: What I try to do is to get all the Childs of a DocumentType, since in the node I have folders, years, etc. I only want the items of Document Type blogPosts

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to get all blogPosts document types in `Section_node`.
in that case try

`Section_pages = Section_node.DescendantsOrSelf().ChildrenOfType("blogPosts");`
also, you can use the other overload of `DescendantsOrSelf<YourDocumentType>()`